# Link2sd can't mount 2nd partition on lineageos

Tags: lineageos, link2sd

I have installed lineage os on a Samsung Galaxy S5. I tried to bring Link2SD to work. I gave it root access via the root add-on in lineageos. Link2SD complains about not being able to mount the 2nd partition which already had worked on a different Phone for the same purpose. I can unmount the second partition in Android settings and then it works, but after rebooting Link2sd can't mount the second partition, because the system already has mounted it.

How can I prevent Android from mounting the second partition before Link2SD can access it?

Android 7.1.2
Lineageos 14.1 20180411

Comment: if your 2nd `partition` is already mounted `Link2SD` should auto detect it is mounted and continue w/ rest of its job. fact that it complains makes me think its likely you haven't mentioned the current `partition` # in block device  e.g.`/dev/block/mmckblk1p2` make sure p2 is in fact the 2nd partition and re-create mount script . in already `mounted` condition use the `unmount` 2nd part & `remount` option to see if that helps